# Using emailjs in react(not typescript)

Tags: reactjs

[image]

[image]

I'm using emailjs library in react. When I submit the form, server is 400 error.
First Image public/index.html.
Second Image is about the form.

I know that the second argument in the `sendForm` method is template_id and the last one is user_id. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not understanding why you are adding script in `public/index.html`. If you  are working with React then you don't need to add any script in HTML.

Points to Remember while implementing emailJS in React:

- Install emailJS and import emailJS from `@emailjs/browser`
- Create a Reference using `useRef` hook.
- Provide necessary credentials.
- Use `ref` in form properly.
- The `name` attribute in input element should exactly match with what you're using in emailJS website.

In `sendEmail` function, I am not seeing any error. I recommend you to recheck html form and follow the code snippet I have attached below.

You can run the following command in terminal to install it.

```
npm install @emailjs/browser --save
```

Then you can follow this code snippet to implement.

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

export const ContactUs = () => {
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', form.current, 'YOUR_USER_ID')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" />
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="user_email" />
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  );
};
```